# Upload docs using zend gdata plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework, gdata, gdata-api, zend-gdata

I am trying to upload a document into Google docs using the `Zend_Gdata` plugin. It uploads fine.

But the document by default becomes private. How can I set it to public. And how can I get the doc id and URL link to my doc so that others can access it to view only?

```
$service = Zend_Gdata_Docs::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client  = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, $service);
$docs    = new Zend_Gdata_Docs($client);
$feed    = $docs->getDocumentListFeed();

$newDocumentEntry = $docs->uploadFile(
    $filename, $name, null, Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI
);
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must supply a different URI as the fourth parameter to the `uploadFile()` function, the one you're using will send docs to private. (Observe below)

Check out the source code from `Zend_Gdata_Docs`.

```
class Zend_Gdata_Docs extends Zend_Gdata
{
    const DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI 
        = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/documents/private/full';
    // ...
```

As you can see, the class `const` is linking to a private path. Instead of using `Zend_Gdata_Docs::DOCUMENTS_LIST_FEED_URI`, you would have to use public. **However**, according to [Google's Documents List Feed API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html#Documents_List_Feed), it appears they *only* accept *private*.

> The visibility parameter has two possible values: private and public.
>
> Note: Currently, private is the only visibility available in the Documents List API. For more information, see [Visibility](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/reference.html#Visibility) values, below.

---

By the way, the end result should return a `Zend_Gdata_App_Entry` object to `$newDocumentEntry` with which I think you should be able to call functions like `$newDocumentEntry->getEditLink()` etc.

If you want to see what else is stored in that object that do this:

```
Zend_Debug::dump($newDocumentEntry);
```

Good luck!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Are you going to aware the bounty? haha

Comment: I am new.. sorry it took so long. I have awarded the bounty.

Comment: Can we publish doc using gdata plugin. I appreciate all your help. Thanks.